# How to get the last path in a URL?

Tags: php, url-parsing

I would like get the last path segment in a URL:

- `http://blabla/bla/wce/news.php` or
- `http://blabla/blablabla/dut2a/news.php`

For example, in these two URLs, I want to get the path segment: 'wce', and 'dut2a'.

I tried to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but I get the whole URL path.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try:

```
$url = 'http://blabla/blablabla/dut2a/news.php';
$tokens = explode('/', $url);
echo $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-2];
```

Assuming `$tokens` has at least 2 elements.

Comment: bahamut100, If this is the right answer, then you should accept it by clicking the white checkmark next to it.

Comment: It will not handhe: http:/ /foobar.com/path/path#fragment/fragment

Comment: @ddimitrov: yes, good point. The more reason for the OP to go with Alex' solution. Can't remove my answer though since it is the accepted answer...

Comment: fragments aren't really a problem as they won't carry over to server. However, an url like this would be a problem: `http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/foo?redirect=http://anothersite.com/default.as‌​px`

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
function getLastPathSegment($url) {
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // to get the path from a whole URL
    $pathTrimmed = trim($path, '/'); // normalise with no leading or trailing slash
    $pathTokens = explode('/', $pathTrimmed); // get segments delimited by a slash

    if (substr($path, -1) !== '/') {
        array_pop($pathTokens);
    }
    return end($pathTokens); // get the last segment
}

    echo getLastPathSegment($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

I've also tested it with a few URLs from the comments. I'm going to have to assume that all paths end with a slash, because I can not identify if /bob is a directory or a file. This will assume it is a file unless it has a trailing slash too.

```
echo getLastPathSegment('http://server.com/bla/wce/news.php'); // wce

echo getLastPathSegment('http://server.com/bla/wce/'); // wce

echo getLastPathSegment('http://server.com/bla/wce'); // bla
```

Comment: +1 For using `parse_url` to get just the URL path. But you need to do that with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as well.

Comment: I thought `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` always came back with `something/like/this` ?

Comment: @alex: No, in PHP it does also contain the query. So URL path and URL query (as in the HTTP request line).

Comment: @gumbo Thanks for the tip, I've made a function wrapper for it too.

Comment: in something like this: `/bla/wce/news.php` wouldn't it return `news.php` instead of `wce` like the OP wanted? Shouldn't it returns the second last element instead of end()? I didn't really test this as it requires PHP version >= 5.1.2 so cmiiw.

Comment: @andyk Thanks for dropping by. I've made some modifications to the function, and run your string and some similar through for their respective outputs.

Answer (score 27):

it is easy

```
<?php
 echo basename(dirname($url)); // if your url/path includes a file
 echo basename($url); // if your url/path does not include a file
?>
```

- `basename` will return the trailing trailing name component of path
- `dirname` will return the parent directory's path

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: could have use some filtering on the url before that. Will fail on something like this `http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/foo?redirect=http://anothersite.com/default.aspx`

Comment: I solved it just using basename(), in you way, I received the second level in "retro"

Comment: `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` did it for me

Comment: @insign Which is what the OP asked

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
 $parts = explode('/', 'your_url_here');
 $last = end($parts);
```

Comment: It can fail if the URL has a trailing slash

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr =  explode("/", $uri);
```

Comment: This is only half of a solution and code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @mickmackusa well you're about 10 years late to the party. Useful feedback.

Comment: I do not discriminate in my volunteerism based on time.  Old low-value posts get read by new visitors and encourage new low-value posts.  I want this place to constantly improve -- no matter how old the content.  Please do _something_ about this post.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
$last_slash = strrpos('/', $url);
$last = substr($url, $last_slash);
```

1: getting the last slash position
2: getting the substring between the last slash and the end of string

Look here: [TEST](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PDLd37)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process an absolute URL, then you can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) (it doesn't work with relative urls).

```
$url = 'http://aplicaciones.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/skypevideo-500x361.jpg?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $url_path);
$last = end($parts);
echo $last;
```

Full code example here: http://codepad.org/klqk5o29

Answer (score 1):

I wrote myself a little function to get the last dir/folder of an url. It only works with real/existing urls, not theoretical ones. In my case, that was always the case, so ...

```
function uf_getLastDir($sUrl)
{
    $sPath = parse_url($sUrl, PHP_URL_PATH);   // parse URL and return only path component 
    $aPath = explode('/', trim($sPath, '/'));  // remove surrounding "/" and return parts into array
    end($aPath);                               // last element of array
    if (is_dir($sPath))                        // if path points to dir
        return current($aPath);                // return last element of array
    if (is_file($sPath))                       // if path points to file
        return prev($aPath);                   // return second to last element of array
    return false;                              // or return false
}
```

Works for me! Enjoy! And kudos to the previous answers!!!

Answer (score 0):

This will keep the part after the last slash.
No worries about explode, when for example no slash is there.

```
$url = 'http://blabla/blablabla/dut2a/news.php';
$url = preg_replace('~.*/~', '', $url);
```

Will give

```
news.php
```