# Get Last Part of URL PHP

Tags: php, url

I'm just wondering how I can extract the last part of a URL using PHP.

The example URL is:

```
http://domain.example/artist/song/music-videos/song-title/9393903
```

Now how can I extract the final part using PHP?

```
9393903
```

There is always the same number of variables in the URL, and the id is always at the end.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match the part of the URL that you want.

In this case, since the pattern is easy, we're looking for a forward slash (`\/` and we have to escape it since the forward slash denotes the beginning and end of the regular expression pattern), along with one or more digits (`\d+`) at the very end of the string (`$`). The parentheses around the `\d+` are used for capturing the piece that we want: namely the end. We then assign the ending that we want (`$end`) to `$matches[1]` (not `$matches[0]`, since that is the same as `$url` (ie the entire string)).

```
$url='http://domain.example/artist/song/music-videos/song-title/9393903';

if(preg_match("/\/(\d+)$/",$url,$matches))
{
  $end=$matches[1];
}
else
{
  //Your URL didn't match.  This may or may not be a bad thing.
}
```

**Note:**  You may or may not want to add some more sophistication to this regular expression. For example, if you know that your URL strings will **always** start with `http://` then the regex can become `/^http:\/\/.*\/(\d+)$/` (where `.*` means zero or more characters (that aren't the newline character)).

Comment: Nice. Could also be done with preg_replace in 1 line. I'll add an answer.

Comment: This solution is probably the slowest of the bunch; not hating, just saying.

Comment: What about example.com/123/my-slug/1235 and you needed 1235?

Comment: It works on strings. But how do you get that last part from URL?

Answer (score 186):

The absolute simplest way to accomplish this, is with [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
echo basename('http://example.com/artist/song/music-videos/song-title/9393903');
```

Which will print

> 9393903

Of course, if there is a query string at the end it will be included in the returned value, in which case the accepted answer is a better solution.

Comment: seriously. After many regular expressions I came around this answer. Why didn't I find this earlier. Plain and simple.

Answer (score 107):

Split it apart and get the last element:

```
$end = end(explode('/', $url));
# or:
$end = array_slice(explode('/', $url), -1)[0];
```

***Edit:*** To support apache-style-canonical URLs, `rtrim` is handy:

```
$end = end(explode('/', rtrim($url, '/')));
# or:
$end = array_slice(explode('/', rtrim($url, '/')), -1)[0];
```

---

A different example which might me considered more readable is ([Demo](http://codepad.org/djyxK3B3)):

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
$end = end($pathFragments);
```

This example also takes into account to only work on the path of the URL.

---

Yet another ***edit*** (years after), canonicalization and easy UTF-8 alternative use included (via PCRE regular expression in PHP):

```
<?php

use function call_user_func as f;
use UnexpectedValueException as e;

$url = 'http://example.com/artist/song/music-videos/song-title/9393903';

$result = preg_match('(([^/]*)/*$)', $url, $m)

    ? $m[1]
    : f(function() use ($url) {throw new e("pattern on '$url'");})
    ;

var_dump($result); # string(7) "9393903"
```

Which is pretty rough but shows how to wrap this this within a `preg_match` call for finer-grained control via PCRE regular expression pattern. To add some sense to this bare-metal example, it should be wrapped inside a function of its' own (which would also make the aliasing superfluous). Just presented this way for brevity.

Comment: Mind the gap: This code exploits something that could be considered a bug in PHP. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @hakre +1, but you'll get nothing if there's trailing slash in the `$url`. Better use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) to remove empty elements first — `$pathFragments = array_filter(explode('/', $path));`

Comment: @jibiel: Or do the `rtrim`-boogie, I edited the answer, see the now third code-example.

Comment: This solution probably performs somewhere in between the `basename`/`str*` solutions and the `preg` solutions if I had to guess. While it's an intuitively simple approach, it comes with some runtime overhead.

Comment: @hakre Demo link is broken. Please kindly fix it

Comment: @MichaelPeter: re-created the demo, the other one I removed as the code is practically there and also the examples changed as PHP has changed. The last example can stay.

Answer (score 32):

If you are looking for a robust version that can deal with any form of [URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), this should do nicely:

```
<?php

$url = "http://foobar.example/foo/bar/1?baz=qux#fragment/foo";
$lastSegment = basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Comment: This is my favorite of the bunch. Robust, performant and concise.

Comment: Much easier than the other ones

Answer (score 15):

```
$id = strrchr($url,"/");
$id = substr($id,1,strlen($id));
```

Here is the description of the `strrchr` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

Comment: This solution is likely the fastest of the bunch, save perhaps the `basename()` solution when applicable.

Comment: this solution is very helpful and very simple

Comment: The solution is  very helpful for me too

Answer (score 7):

Another option:

```
$urlarray=explode("/",$url);
$end=$urlarray[count($urlarray)-1];
```

Answer (score 6):

One of the most elegant solutions was here [Get characters after last / in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361741/get-characters-after-last-in-url)

by DisgruntledGoat

```
$id = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```

> strrpos gets the position of the last occurrence of the slash; substr
>   returns everything after that position.

Answer (score 3):

One liner: `$page_path = end(explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')));`

Get URI, trim slashes, convert to array, grab last part

Comment: causes error with current PHP(Jan 2020): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4636183/571723

Answer (score 3):

A fail safe solution would be:

Referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2273328/2062851

```php
function getLastPathSegment($url) {
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // to get the path from a whole URL
    $pathTrimmed = trim($path, '/'); // normalise with no leading or trailing slash
    $pathTokens = explode('/', $pathTrimmed); // get segments delimited by a slash

    if (substr($path, -1) !== '/') {
        array_pop($pathTokens);
    }
    return end($pathTokens); // get the last segment
}

echo getLastPathSegment($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //9393903
```

Answer (score 1):

this will do the job easily to get the last part of the required URL

```
$url="http://domain.example/artist/song/music-videos/song-title/9393903";
$requred_string= substr(strrchr($url, "/"), 1);
```

this will get you the string after first "/" from the right.

Comment: Do mind: if there's a trailing slash at the end this will fail. See the comments at the solution of hakre and his edit. Check out Peter's solution: the basename() function is made for this.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$mylink = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$link_array = explode('/',$mylink);
echo $lastpart = end($link_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLastPathSegment($url) {
    $arr = explode('/', $url);
    return $arr[count($arr) - 1];
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**1-liner**

```
$end = preg_replace( '%^(.+)/%', '', $url );

// if( ! $end ) no match.
```

This simply removes everything before the last slash, including it.

Answer (score 0):

One line working answer:

```
$url = "http://www.yoursite/one/two/three/drink";
echo $end = end((explode('/', $url)));
```

Output: **drink**

Comment: Ho do i get only two/three/drink from the url ?