# How to get string before last slash and after second last slash in URL

Tags: php, regex

If I have a URL look like this:

http://wwww.example/test1/test2/test3/

How can I retrieve string `test3` from the url above?

Comment: `echo basename($url);`

Comment: Duplicate of [Get Last Part of URL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$str = explode("/","http://wwww.example/test1/test2/test3/");
echo $str[count($str)-2];
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/83914

Answer (score 4):

Regular expression solution.

```
$url = 'http://wwww.example/test1/test2/test3/';

preg_match('#.*/(.*)/$#', $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/83928)

Answer (score 1):

Using capturing group, `$`:

```
preg_match('!/([^/]+)/[^/]*$!', 'http://wwww.example/test1/test2/test3/', $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/7EVfZa

Answer (score 0):

So [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) does exactly that.

```
$url = 'http://www.example/test1/test2/test3/';
echo basename($url); // returns : test3;
```