# How to get second last word from url in PHP codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, split

I need to get second last word of a url which is split by `"/"`.I have tried

```
$refer_split = explode("/", $refer);
    echo $refer_split[6];
```

but it is not working in case of small urls.
please suggest a good way to find the secondlast word in php

Comment: Count the number of array entries, and do some most basic math?

Comment: `echo $refer_split[count($refer_split)-2];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get string before last slash and after second last slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823748/how-to-get-string-before-last-slash-and-after-second-last-slash-in-url)

Comment: In codeigniter you can use the uri segments() https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 6):

use CI Built in Functions

```
$url_count=$this->uri->total_segments();
echo  $this->uri->segment($url_count-1);
```

-1 is used because `$this->uri->total_segments()` this give you the last word and -1 will give second last

Comment: since your using CI might as well use some of its ready functions

Comment: if it works for you and it meets your requirement...accept the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$refer = "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190344/replacing-urls-with-dummy-urls";
$refer_split = explode("/", $refer);
echo (count($refer_split) > 1) ? $refer_split[ count($refer_split) - 2] : 'no parts available'; 
// echo's '190344'
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba25303941f8ce345893d132d2215ceed13c8a07)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$split = explode("/", $refer);
$count = count($split);
if($count > 1){
    echo $split[$count - 2];
}
```

This code won't work if your url count is 1, because you'd be trying to access element `-1` which won't exist.