# Get last part of a string preceded by a forward slash

Tags: php

I have the following viemo url:

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/5836196
```

How would I be able to get the last part of the url 5836196 using php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php

Comment: Tried `echo basename($url);`?

Comment: to be on the safe side you could use a combination of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php) and [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/function.pathinfo.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`substr`](https://www.php.net/substr)/[`strrpos`](https://www.php.net/strrpos)-

```
substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '/' )+1 );
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/136193)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$url='http://player.vimeo.com/video/5836196';
echo end(explode('/', $url));
```