# PHP strpos issue

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match, strpos

I visit my page `www.mysite.com/theme/test/index.php` which contains the code below. I expect to see the word `test` inside the `h1` but it is blank :-( Can someone explain where I've gont wrong?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ((false !== strpos($url,'theme')) || (false !== strpos($url,'colours'))) {

    if(preg_match("/\/(\d+)$/",$url,$matches)) { $end=$matches[1]; }
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo ucwords(str_replace("-"," ",$end)); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your preg_match is wrong. `\d` means digit. You don't have any in your url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure exactly what information you have going through your script when it is being run, but my best guess is that `$end` is never being set.

Check to make sure that your regular expression matches, otherwise `$end` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

@Marcin was right.

`$end = end((explode('/', rtrim($url, '/'))));`

Found this useful: [Get Last Part of URL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php)