# Doing an if statement with wordpress <?php the_permalink(); ?>

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make a condition when my template loads, if the perma link is /xxxx/butiker then do this...

And if /xxxx/services loop this.

or if /xxxx/cafeer loop this.

If I render out `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` I get the full link, but I need some code to actually just check the .com/xxx/THIS part. Could someone assist?

Answer (score 1):

Split the URL using PHPs [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$link = get_permalink();
$temp = explode("/",$link);
print_r($temp);
```

The [`get_permalink()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function returns the URL, and `print_r` prints the array. Get your part which you want to check in if condition like;

For example:

```
Array ( [0] => www.xyz.com
        [1] => xxx
        [2] => services
      )
```

---

```
if($temp[2] == "services"){
     //your loop for services ,cafeer etc..
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer and explanation so +1 but could be better I think if using `basename()` or `end()` rather than `temp[2]` as the url might have more parts to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php