# pcre. How to get last part of url

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

Have a url kind of this

```
https://example.com.ua/part1/part2/part3/product-123.html
```

How to get `product-123.html` with regular expression?

I tried this:

```
echo 
preg_replace('#/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.html)$#','$1','https://example.com.ua/part1/part2/part3/product-123.html');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Last Part of URL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preg_replace` only replaces what you have it find. In this case `product-123.html`. So you're replacing `/product-123.html` with `product-123.html` and the `https://example.com.ua/part1/part2/part3` remains untouched.

To replace everything and only keep the match you'd do

```
echo 
preg_replace('#.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.html)$#','$1','https://example.com.ua/part1/part2/part3/product-123.html');
```

you don't need a regex though to accomplish this task, and if you did it'd probably be cleaner to use `preg_match`.

Here's a `preg_match` approach:

```
preg_match('#[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.html$#', 'https://example.com.ua/part1/part2/part3/product-123.html', $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/4o9RM

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/6dytu0/2/

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regular expression for that

There's more than one way of doing it.

Look into [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

> parse_url(): This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present.

That will get you most of the way there and will also separate the host for you. Then you just explode your way to the last part using explode() and end().

```
$url = parse_url('http://example.com/project/controller/action/param1/param2');
$url['last'] = end(explode('/', $url[path]));

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => example.com
    [path] => /project/controller/action/param1/param2
    [last] => param2
)
```

Or you can go straight to the point like this:

```
$last = ltrim(strrchr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/'), '/');
```

You can also just go a head and use explode() in combination of end() directly on the URL. (it's also a lot shorter if you don't need the extra information of parse_url)

```
$last = end(explode('/', $url));
```

You can also just use [basename](http://php.net/basename)() like this

```
$url = "http://example.com/project/controller/action/param1/param2";
$last = basename($url);
// Output: param2
```

Comment: Using `PHP_URL_PATH` as second parameter, `parse_url` returns a string with the path instead of an array. Example: https://3v4l.org/ZgVAS

Comment: Nice add Casimir! Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why regex?

```
$str ="https://example.com.ua/part1/part2/part3/product-123.html";
Echo Substr($str, strrpos($str, "/")+1);
```

https://3v4l.org/rJiGL

Strrpos finds the last `/` and returns position.

---

Here is a preg_replace that will work if you must use regex.
https://regex101.com/r/6zJwBo/1

```
$re = '/.*\//';
$str = 'https://example.com.ua/part1/part2/part3/product-123.html';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Is my answer particulary bad or something?