# How can I get the end of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, substring

### Substr PHP

I have a `string` like `http://domain.sf/app_local.php/foo/bar/33`.

The last characters are the `id` of an element. Its length could be more than one, so I can not use:

```
substr($dynamicstring, -1);
```

In this case, it must be:

```
substr($dynamicstring, -2);
```

How can I get the characters after "/bar/" on the `string` without depending on the length?

Comment: You could use `explode()`, use `/` as delimiter and fetch the last element of the resulting array. http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), like this:

```
$id = explode('/',$var);
```

And take the element where you had the id.

Comment: Same as Luke Taylor's answer, this won't work because end is expecting a reference, not a value.

Comment: Yes, it could be a solution. But that impossible get the `GET` values.
I dont need the `GET` values so im gonna use this solution

Comment: $id is an array so i have my value in `$id[1]` Thanks @Eduardo Gabaldón

Answer (score 5):

To ensure you are getting an immediate section after the bar, use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
preg_match('~/bar/([^/?&#]+)~', $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // 33
```

Comment: Easily the best solution here, the others all ignore the possibility of GET data or make assumptions about the ID.

Comment: i need to initialize `$matches` ?
I get `$matches = {array}[0]` so it dont works to me... Im doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't need to initialize it. Are you doing something other than [**this**](https://3v4l.org/71njj)? @Oscar

Answer (score 2):

You could use [explode('/', $dynamicstring)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string into an array of the strings inbetween each `/`. Then you could use `end()` on the result of this to get the last part.

```
$id = end(explode('/', $dynamicstring));
```

Comment: This won't work because end is expecting an array, as a reference.

Comment: @omerowitz It works, it just triggers a notice as well. The return from `explode` should definitley be assigned to an intermediate variable before being passed to `end` to avoid this.

Comment: As I've did and explained in my answer.

Comment: I have the next output trying your answer: `Only variables should be passed by reference`
But yes, it helps. I can use explode and then get the end of array but ignore the possibility of the GET data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dynamicstring = 'http://domain.sf/app_local.php/foo/bar/33';

// split your string into an array with /
$parts = explode('/', $dynamicstring);

// move the array pointer to the end
end($parts);

// return the current position/value of the $parts array
$id = current($parts);

// reset the array pointer to the beginning => 0
// if you want to do any further handling
reset($parts);

echo $id;
// $id => 33
```

Test it [yourself here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b9df5d76b8f88c6af624833ffd71417bac76300).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to do it:

```
$dynamicstring = "http://domain.sf/app_local.php/foo/bar/33";
if (preg_match('#/([0-9]+)$#', $dynamicstring, $m)) {
    echo $m[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out myself before answering. Other answers are reasonable too, but this will work according to your need...

```
<?php
    $url = "http://domain.sf/app_local.php/foo/bar/33";
    $id = substr($url, strpos($url, "/bar/") + 5);
    echo $id;
```

Comment: So what should the OP do when his `33` turns into `3306` or in `3`?

Answer (score -3):

Please find the below answer.

```
$str = "http://domain.sf/app_local.php/foo/bar/33";
$splitArr = explode('/', explode('//', $str)[1]);
var_dump($splitArr[count($splitArr)-1]);
```

Comment: Why should OP use count if length should be avoided?

Comment: My dearest lord... For which reasons are you exploding by `/` then by `//`, and getting the rest of after second explode... then `count - 1`? What happends with this when instead of full URL I provide just a pathname?