# Get the last string of URL's

Tags: php

I am getting data from a page like this:

```
<?php $speaker = $page->uri();
  $speakerEvents = page('program')->grandchildren()->filter(function($child) use($speaker) {
  $speakers = $child->speaker()->toStructure();
  return $speakers->findBy('selectspeaker', $speaker);
});

echo $speakerEvents;                

?>
```

**It's output is:**

```
"page/page/pageIWant
page/page/pageIWant"
```

**The Result I want is**

```
pageIWant
pageIWant
```

**I tried to get the last name with**

```
echo basename($speakerEvents);
```

But I only get one of the last `pageIWant`

How do I get the last pages without removing the first URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Last Part of URL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `explode` method to get array of URL

```
<?php
    $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $link_array = explode('/',$link);
    echo $page = end($link_array);
?>
```

If your output is

> page/page/pageIWant 
>   page/page/pageIWant

```
<?php
    $text = "page/page/pageIWant";
    $text_arr = explode('/',$text);
    echo $page = end($text_arr);
    // this will print: pageIWant
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string has a line break as path separator. You need to split lines by either `\r\n` (CR-LF), `\n`, or `\r` which can be done with `preg_split`. If you can ensure one of the formats, you can also use the simple `explode` function.

```
foreach (preg_split('~(?:\r?\n|\r)~u', $speakerEvents) as $path)
  echo basename($path) , PHP_EOL;
```

As *AbraCadaver* noted, you can add the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to `preg_split` if you do not want empty lines to be handled.

If the double qoutes you show in the question are part of the string, you need further more to trim the string:

```
foreach (preg_split('~(?:\r?\n|\r)~u', trim($speakerEvents, '"')) as $path)
  echo basename($path) , PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Good one, might also add `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` just in case.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thank you, added your hint to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string e.g.

`$array = explode('/', 'page/page/pageIWant');`

Then you can retrieve it using the index like so:

`$array[(count($array) - 1)];`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer I tried it like this:
`$array = explode('/', $speakerEvents);echo $array[(count($array) - 1)];`
Unfortunately I still get only one last `pageIWant`

Comment: You've made two lines one string in your question, should that be two strings or you need the third and last item? If it's the same format every time, you can simply just use index's 2 and 5.

Comment: so it will be the same format every time. On some pages it will be more lines and on some it will be less. Could you help me here?

Comment: At the time of the code executing, do you know the name of the pages you want? Because you could always loop through the array and check with a simple [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: of course! Dump! Its now working as I expected with a loop.