# how to store the url sting parameter in the $variable

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i am working on a wordpress website and i am little stuck into one situation,

```
https://jobicons.com/newsite/my-profile/
```

the above is the url of my web site i only want to store the my-profile parameter in the $variable , is there any way how can i do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Last Part of URL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php)

Comment: What do you mean by "the $variable"?

Answer (score 0):

using php it is as simple as doing this:

```
<?php echo basename($URL);
```

but since you're using wordpress, this is how you should be able to get the slug name for a post

```
<?php 
   global $post;
   $post_slug = $post->post_name;
?>
```