# How do I return last four paths in url?

Tags: php, url, path, explode, permalinks

Similar to this question: [How to get the last path in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273280/how-to-get-the-last-path-in-the-url)

...Except instead of returning only the *last path* in the URL, I want to return the last four:

```
<?php 
  $url = 'http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog-name/2012/04/21/title-of-the-blog-post';
  print_r(parse_url($url));
  $url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
  $parts = explode('/', $url_path);
  $relative_permalink = end($parts);
echo $relative_permalink;
?>
```

The code above is from the earlier Stack Overflow item I linked to. It kind of does what I want, except it returns only title-of-blog-post; I want to return everything after /blog-name/, like this:

```
/20120/04/21/title-of-blog-post
```

This code also sort of gets me there:

```
$url_endpoint = http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog-name/2012/04/21/title-of-the-blog-post;
$url_endpoint = parse_url( $url_endpoint );
$url_endpoint = $url_endpoint['path'];
```

Except that it also returns /blog-name/ and everything after it. I want to exclude /blog-name/

Any ideas for how I can manipulate either of these snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [array_slice](https://www.php.net/array_slice):

```
$relative_permalink = array_slice($parts, -4);
```

**--Update--**

```
$url = 'http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog-name/2012/04/21/blog-title/';
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

// We are exploding on /, so there may be some empty array elements
// passing them through array_filter will remove them
$parts = array_filter(explode('/', $url_path), 'strlen');

// Grab the last 4 elements of array
$relative_permalink = array_slice($parts, -4);

// Put humpty back together again
echo implode('/', $relative_permalink);
```

Your question had a hard req of the last 4, which this will accomplish, however Blair McMillan's answer is more flexible as it will allow you to take anything after 'blog-name', so keep that in mind.

Comment: That makes sense in my head, but not quite working when I try to run it: http://codepad.org/XklfJu7V -- any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
list(, $last_four) = explode('/blog-name/', $url);
```

Comment: a) It doesn't necessarily give the last 4 parts, just everything after '/blog-name/' - whatever that is
b) It depends on the path the file is in, which it shouldn't

Comment: Which is what she's looking for. It's a wordpress blog. It's going to always be in that format.

Comment: He's looking for the last 4 parts of a URL, your code might work for his example. It might not for the actual use cases.

Comment: Re-read the question. *She* wants *everything* after `/blog-name/`. My code does that even if the format changes.

Comment: ´I want to return the last four´ Don't get me wrong, I never said your solution is invalid - there are just more cleaner ways in my opinion (see Mike Purcells array_slice)

Comment: Cleaner then a simple one-liner?

Comment: Because the length of code directly relates to how clean it is? As I said: It will probably work (what happens if the post title equals the blog-name though? Just a question...)

Comment: And the odds of that happening is...?

Comment: Even a simple `str_replace("http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog-name", "", $url);` or `substr(...)` would work. There are many different ways to solve this, I'm just rating them. I apologize if this hurts your feelings...

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything after the first one, wouldn't it be easier to `array_shift()` off the first element and return the others?

```
<?php 
  $url = 'http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog-name/2012/04/21/title-of-the-blog-post';
  print_r(parse_url($url));
  $url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
  $parts = explode('/', $url_path);
  $static_name = array_shift($parts);
  $relative_permalink = implode('/', $parts);
  echo $relative_permalink;
?>
```

Comment: Definitely a more flexible option, if the number after 'blog-post' is expected to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog-name/2012/04/21/title-of-the-blog-post';
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $url_path);
$relative_permalink = implode('/', array_slice($parts, -4));
echo $relative_permalink;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the path in a URL, you can use [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$url = 'http://blogs.mydomain.com/blog-name/2012/04/21/title-of-the-blog-post';
$urlInfo = parse_url($url);
print_r($urlInfo);
$urlPath = $urlInfo['path'];
echo "\n";
```