# Regular expression to get the path from an URL

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the last path in the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273280/how-to-get-the-last-path-in-the-url)

I'm not very good with regex as I haven't yet come to understand how it fully works to get the right results. I need a regex expression or php function to strip out the beginning of a url to get the last bit without the variables on it.

**Input :**  http: // www.site.com/more/more/thepartidneed?part=Idontneed

**Other Input** : www.site.com/more/more/thepartineed?partidontneed

**Other input** : site.com/more/more/partineed

**Results Desired After Stripped** : 
"thepartineed"

Is this possible?

Comment: lots more duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+last+path+in+url+php - please use the search function before asking questions. [We expect you to do research.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)

Comment: I apologize, I couldn't come up with the word "path". :\

Comment: See: [parse_url()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Should be easy from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to check if given URL contains `http(s)://` at the beginning, if not - append it and then do

```
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
var_dump($parsed_url);
```

You will get something like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(8) "site.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(20) "/more/more/partineed"
}
```

If you need only last bit of path you can do

```
echo array_pop(explode('/', $parsed_url['path']));
```

Comment: The output you quote is for `parse_url($url)`, yet you're supplying the `PHP_URL_PATH` constant, so `$parsed_url` will be just the path segment: `"/more/more/partineed"`... So no arrays are involved...

Comment: @ircmaxell yep, you're right. My bad

Comment: Yep, ended up using parse_url and some more filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input is always some sort of url:

```
.+/([^?]+).*
```

Your part should be in identifier 1