# Echo part of the current url gives an error

Tags: php

This is my url form:

```
http://dev.test.de/profile/id/
```

I am trying to echo the id of the current url.

```
$parts = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$path_parts= explode('/', $parts[path]);
echo $user = $path_parts[2];
```

But it says:

Warning: Illegal string offset ‘path’

thank you

Comment: call explode as  `$path_parts = explode('/', $parts);`  there is no index such `$parts[path]` . `$parts` is a string. you are exploding it into an array

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273280/how-to-get-the-last-path-in-the-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$parts` variable is a string.

```
$parts = 'http://' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$path_parts= explode('/', $parts);
echo $user = $path_parts[4];
```

This will return the *id*.

Comment: Did you try this? Its wrong. [2] isn't the correct index.

Answer (score 1):

This, should work for you.

```
$parts = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$path_parts= explode('/', $parts);
echo $user = $path_parts[4];
```

it is the 4th index because

- [0] contains `"http:"`
- [1] contains `""`
- [2] contains `"dev.test.de"`
- [3] contains `"profile"`
- [4] contains `"id"`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$parts = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path_parts= explode('/', $parts);
echo $user = $path_parts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your example.

```
$parts = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

`$_SERVER` is a super global array and `HTTP_HOST` is one of it's indices. As this is an associative array you need to enclose the index name with a pair of either single quotes, or double quotes. So it should be `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, and because this is inside a string you need to use `{}` to interpolate the variable/array name. So it looks like:

```
$parts = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
```

or simply separate them as

```
$parts = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Your second problem is:

```
$path_parts= explode('/', $parts[path]);
```

as far as your code goes `$parts` is a string not an array, so `$parts[path]` has no meaning here. It should be:

```
$path_parts= explode('/', $parts);
```