# Trim function is removing my last character in different strings

Tags: php, url

I want to get last path of the URL **Admin & Planner**  but this trim is not working for Planner it is giving **Planne** output. I tried searching couple of options on stackoverflow but its not working with me.
First URL : http://localhost/hydro-railway/Admin/ 
Output: Admin 
Second URL : http://localhost/hydro-railway/Planner/ 
Output: Planne

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' 
            ? "https" 
            : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$url=trim($url,"http://localhost/hydro-railway/");
echo("after: ".$url."<br>");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last path in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273280/how-to-get-the-last-path-in-a-url)

Comment: Also check what `trim()` does with the second parameter - it's a list of chars to remove and not a specific string to remove.